# Can't understand this LINE (in_array)

Tags: php, arrays, function, return, boolean

I found this code on a website to convert celcius, to farentheit and kelvin.
But I can't understand one line inside.

```php
function conv_temp($val , $type_val , $type_wanted) {
  $tab_val = array("C", "F", "K");
  if (!(in_array($type_val, $tab_val) && in_array($type_wanted,$tab_val)))
    return 0;
  switch ($type_val) {
    case "C" : // degrees Celsius
      switch ($type_wanted) {
        case "C" :
          return $val;
        case "F" :
          return ($val * 9 / 5 + 32);
        case "K" :
          return ($val + 273.16);
    case "F" : // degrees Fahrenheit
      switch ($type_wanted) {
        case "C" :
          return (($val - 32) * 5 / 9);
        case "F" :
          return $val;
        case "K" :
          return ((($val - 32) * 5 / 9) + 273.16);
    case "K" : // degrees Kelvin
      switch ($type_wanted) {
        case "C" :
          return ($val - 273.16);
        case "F" :
          return (($val - 273.16) * 9 / 5 + 32);
        case "K" :
          return $val;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

echo conv_temp(5,'C','F')."\n";

?>;
```

Why does `in_array` have to `return 0`?
I deleted this line and the function is still working.

Comment: [It doesn't return 0 here.](https://3v4l.org/bfW5t)

Comment: @Jeto I don't understand why after in array there is "Return 0"

Comment: what is the usefulness of this line

Comment: @Jeto same for the in array? Is it important to add it here?

Comment: 0 is probably an error code when you pass values that are not 'C', 'F' or 'K'. Try `echo conv_temp(5, 'C', 'Z');` and you'll get 0 because `Z` is invalid. It doesn't matter if you never do that.

Comment: @Jeto thanks, and do you know what means the "!" before the " (in_array" ?

Comment: is it like "!="?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `return 0` is to ensure that the `switch` case should work only if you use the values with in the `$tab_val` array.

```
$tab_val = array("C", "F", "K");
```

So if you use any symbols other than `C`,`F` or `K` the function will immediately return 0 without executing the reaming code.

So your code will work without that line until you enter an invalid type.

If you enter invalid type `return 0` makes the output result to 0, else it will be blank.

Even if you use `c`, `k` or `f` instead of `C`,`K` or `F` the result wil be 0 since the values are case sensitive

```
echo conv_temp(5,'C','f')."\n";
```

The output of the above code will be 0 since we used `f` instead of `F`

Answer (score 0):

It's to guard against cases where a user tries to call the function with a temperature symbol that doesn't exist:

```php
// EXAMPLE 1
echo conv_temp(5,'C','F')."\n";
// Output: 41

// EXAMPLE 2
echo conv_temp(5,'C','J')."\n";
// Output: 0
```

If you remove the test and run Example 2 again, you get no output:

```php
echo conv_temp(5,'C','J')."\n";
// Output:
```

## EDIT

If the `0` is being used as an error code as suggested in the comments, I'd say it's not the best idea to do so. What if you input a temperature that actually converts to 0? :

```php
$temp = conv_temp(-273.16,'C','K');
if ($temp == 0) {
  echo "Conversion failed";
} else {
  echo "$temp";
}

// Output: Conversion failed
```

Comment: @LionelSYMR no problem, I've added some detail to my answer.

Comment: do you know what means the "!" before the " (in_array" ?

Comment: It's the logical NOT operator: https://www.w3resource.com/php/operators/logical-operators.php